# Java - Looping 2d Array to find index of a value not working

Tags: java

I know I'm making an error somewhere in this code, but I can't figure it out.  The player1.getId(); returns a value of 1 just so you are aware.  I'm trying to print the index of the array where the value is 1.  At the end of the code, I expected currentX to be 0 and currentY to be 0, but they were both 9.  Any help would be super.

```
int[][] grid = {
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}
};

int currentX = 0;
int currentY = 0;

grid[0][0] = player1.getId();

grid[0][9] = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
        if (grid[i][j] == player1.getId());
        {
            currentX = i;
            currentY = j;
        }
        System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
    }

}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Player1 is currently in row " + currentX + " and column " + currentY);
```

Comment: are you sure you want grid[0].length in your inner for, seems like you are after grid[i].length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the semicolon(`;`) at the end of `if (grid[i][j] == player1.getId());`

**Consider how works `if` statement of java**

The `if` statement of java executes it's block code if the expression of `if` statement is `true`. Semi colon ends a statement of java. If you put empty semi colon after if statement it counts as an empty statement. So, `if` statement does nothing when executing `if` statement which having semi colon at the end. Java compiler compiles your code similarly as follows.

```
if (grid[i][j] == player1.getId()){
    //nothing here
}

{
    currentX = i;
    currentY = j;
}
```

**See what happens when other kind statement had semi colon at the end.**

- **`while` loop**

  ```
      while (expression);
      {
          //something goes here 
      }
  ```

The condition can be `true` or `false` when initializing `while` loop. If the condition is `true` it makes an infinite loop. Nothing will execute after the line. If expression is `false`, it executes once the expected content of `while` loop.

- **`switch (integer);` and `catch (Exception e);`**

It fails to compile and getting an exception `{ expected`

Comment: I'll just add that you can prevent this kind of mistake in the future by putting opening braces on the same line

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I am embarrassed by this oversight.

Comment: Train to put open braces, then you will not get this bug. This kind of bug are hard to identify when it is in a complex code.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is `true` here (if `player1.getId() == 1`):

`if(grid[i][j] == player1.getId());`

But the code contains a logical error: a group of operators here - *the empty operator* `;` and it will be executed...

`currentX` and `currentY` always will be equals the length of the array.

```
currentX = grid.length;
currentY = grid[0].length;
```